# Eclipse "invalid resource directory name"

Tags: android, windows, eclipse

Whenever I try to add a resource folder to my Android project in Eclipse (3.7.0), I always get the following error:

```
invalid resource directory name: C:\path_to_project\res/new_folder_name
```

You'll notice that the slash goes the wrong way for the newly created folder, so I'm guessing this is some sort of Windows-specific issue, though I can't for the life of me figure out how to resolve it.

Here's some of the ways I tried creating the folder:

- Right click on "res" in project in Eclipse -> New -> Folder
- Create the new folder through Windows Explorer and import it into the Eclipse project
- Remove the project from my workspace entirely, create the folder in Explorer, and re-import the entire project into Eclipse
- Do the same using the command line, both Cygwin and DOS

In all of these cases, I end up with the slash going the wrong way.

What am I missing?

Comment: What's the name of this damn new folder?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Folders in the res-Folder are only allowed to be those defined by Android, for example "drawable". See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html for more information. If you choose anything else you get the error "invalid resource directory name" when building your project.

Comment: good to know, created a folder called nav and got the same error. but now works. thanks!

Comment: @ajbraus: Without knowing more details: You could try closing your IDE, rename the folder in the stored folder data structure and then restart Android Studio/Eclipse. It should then sync and show the correct new name.

Comment: @sunadorer good idea. But as soon as I open my IDE Eclipse, the crunch folder is back. So weird.

Comment: On a side note, this is also true of files. I had a build blocked simply because a file made its way to that res folder... Removing it solved the issue for me

Answer (score 6):

Just learned something!

FYI I 'm trying to store some audio files, created the folder audio under `\res` and got the same error. Then after some reading somebody wrote somewhere that `\assets` folder is a good folder for data files that don't change. So I placed my audio under `\assets`.

Comment: Don't drag your folder from 'res' to 'assets'. Delete your folder under 'res' and re-create it under 'assets'.

Answer (score 4):

in bin/res/ you have a folder with the name of crunch delete that folder and the problem will be fixed I don't have idea why, but when you create a project in aide the aide dont create the crunch folder

Answer (score 2):

In my actionbarsherlock folder. bin/res there was crunch folder. When I deleted it. It work fine. Don't know from where this come from ?

Answer (score 0):

For putting your resources like .mp3 files, create a folder named /raw under /res folder and store your files in it.And of course clean your project after this.

This will definitely solve your problem.