# generating R.java file from command line “invalid resource directory name”

Tags: java, android, command-line

I need to build the R.java file from resource using the command line. I do this using the following Java program. 
I get the Errors:

> invalid resource directory name: C:\Users\Muzammil-Husnain\testing\Soothing-snow-fall\res/drawable-tvdpi

and

> invalid resource directory name: C:\Users\Muzammil-Husnain\testing\Soothing-snow-fall\res/drawable-xhdpi

If I remove these two folders from my res folder it says

> ERROR: input directory 'Files' does not exist

Here is my code:

```
public static String ProjectPath = "C:\\Users\\Muzammil-Husnain\\testing\\Soothing-snow-fall";
public static String ANDROID_HOME = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk";

public static void generateRfile() {
    try {
        File projectDirectoryFile = new File(ProjectPath);
        String command = "aapt package -v -f -m "+
        " -S \""+projectDirectoryFile.getCanonicalPath()+"/res\"" +
        " -J \""+projectDirectoryFile.getCanonicalPath()+"/gen\"" +
        " -M \""+projectDirectoryFile.getCanonicalPath()+"/AndroidManifest.xml\"" +
        " -I C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Android\\android-sdk\\platforms\\android-21\\android.jar\"";
        System.out.println("Directory Path : "+projectDirectoryFile.getCanonicalPath());
        System.out.println(command);
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", command);
        processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while (true) {
            line = r.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(line);
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RunApplicationOnPrject.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

[image: Here is my resource Directory]

Comment: It looks to me that the path to the directory is invalid. Especially the last slash instead of a backslash is a problem. It should be: **C:\Users\Muzammil-Husnain\testing\Soothing-snow-fall\res\drawable-tvdpi** instead of  **C:\Users\Muzammil-Husnain\testing\Soothing-snow-fall\res/drawable-tvdpi**. How do you append the last directory name?

Comment: @Nessuno
Thanks for Replying Dear path to the drawables-tvdpi and other dpi folders is determined by the aapt (android asset packaging tool) the error is only for tvdpi and xhdpi folder. that's problem why is it so only for these two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

android jar file was not being located by the aapt the issue was starting quote was missing from the code

```
 " -I C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Android\\android-sdk\\platforms\\android-21\\android.jar\""
```

while ending quote were present and url to the android.jar was broken so I change. So I changed my code to

```
 " -I \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Android\\android-sdk\\platforms\\android-21\\android.jar\""
```

and problem is fixed :-)

Answer (score 3):

You are mounting a command line to call cmd.exe, and the directory isn't within double quotes, so the cmd.exe is interpreting the "Files" in C:\Program Files as different arguments. Try to place the directories/files specifications between double quotes, as this:

```
    String command = "aapt package -v -f -m "+
    " -S \""+projectDirectoryFile.getCanonicalPath()+"/res\"" +
    " -J \""+projectDirectoryFile.getCanonicalPath()+"/gen\"" +
    " -M \""+projectDirectoryFile.getCanonicalPath()+"/AndroidManifest.xml\"" +
    " -I \""+ANDROID_HOME+"/platforms/android-18/android.jar\"";
```

Comment: I tried the given solution but Problem persist in my case.

Comment: Did you try deleting the the wrong resource directories and applying this solution?

Comment: @Nessuno Yes I tried deleting wrong directories than second error "ERROR: input directory 'Files' does not exist" occured

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

A friend of mine pointed me towards [gradle](https://gradle.org/). It is a sophisticated build automation tool, which can also be used from the command line. Since setting up resources and assets for Android is always a nightmare you might want to take a look at it. There seem to be a few tutorials for creating Android apps like [this one](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBuild/article.html) or [this one](http://rominirani.com/2014/08/19/gradle-tutorial-part-6-android-studio-gradle/).

---

According to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168706/eclipse-invalid-resource-directory-name/7168818) you might have to jump through some hoops to add your resource folders correctly to your project.

Another problem that [sometimes comes up](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/issues/detail?id=282) are outdated aapt and/or Android SDK versions. You should check if you can update those to any newer version.

Comment: with respect and Thanks I have renamed xhdpi to xdpi but still same error persist ** invalid resource directory name: C:\Users\Muzammil-Husnain\testing\Soothing-snow-fall\res/drawable-xdpi **

Comment: No I'm not using any IDE but I'm trying to make a java software to make apps from already template android application in which I wil cahnge resources from my editor and It will make apk for me.
And yes template android application  was build in Eclipse.

Comment: I created android proect by comman line and still I get auto generated xhdpi folder so the problem isn't the xhspi converting to xdpi

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html here is reference to the directory naming qualifier which states  drawable-xhdpi and drawable-tvdpi are valid.

Comment: I guess the poster of the other question used an outdated version of `aapt` then. The thing is that this leaves me stumped with your problem. I guess it's a mix of missing resource setup and the path problem adressed by alexander picoli.

Comment: Dear Thanks for your attention regarding my question, The Problem isn't with path I'm sured about that and I have changed code acording to @alexander picoli but problem persist.
Well Thanks and  you are not stumped as you fought well. :-P
"Success never lies in result but in effort." (~someone I don't know)